# Loop SQL statements

Tags: java, sql

My code obtains 5,000 rows and does some processing, then stops. I want to loop the code so that after it processes 5,000 rows it will obtain another 5,000 and process again. I want it to do this until there are no more rows left.

I can't wrap my head around this logic, if someone could give me an example or pseudo-code that would be awesome.

```
@Component("Inv226")
@Scope("prototype")
public class Inv226 extends BatchProgram {

    @Override
    public void process() {
        // Make it so the printing goes to the result page.
        this.webOn();
        print(" ", false);
        print("*****************************************", false);
        print("** B.INV226 Begins: " + getTime() + " " + date(YearFormat.YYYY), false);
        print("*****************************************", false);
        // Find the first 5,000 records to remove.

        //TODO find a way to keep looping
        // and obtaining another set of 5,000 records
        // when we're done processing each result set
        Calendar limitDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        limitDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1095);
        MList<Inv> delList = new MList<>(Inv.class, //
                "CREATE_DATE < ? " //
                        + "order by CREATE_DATE " //
                        + "offset 0 rows " //
                        + "fetch next 5000 rows ONLY", //
                limitDate);
        // Set the commit limit.
        int commitLimit = 50;
        int i = 0;
        int delCount = 0;
        // Loop through them...
        for (Inv inv : delList) {
            // Remove each.
            inv.delete();
            if (++i >= commitLimit) {
                try {
                    this.commit();
                    print("Succesfully deleted " + i + " records");
                    delCount += i;
                    i = 0;
                    // Do we want a delay here?
                } catch (MccMidusException mme) {
                    // Is this a timestamp mismatch?
                    if ("0080".equals(mme.getErrorCode())) {
                        // Poke the record so the next invocation of Eddbl will process it correctly,
                        // along with the other 49 records in this block.
                        // Assuming the poke is successful, processing on the remaining Edb003 records in the
                        // block of 5000 will continue.
                        this.getIoHarness().pokeUow(mme.getUow());
                        // Call commit to get a new transaction started.
                        this.commit();
                        // Reset the counter.
                        i = 0;
                    } else {
                        throw mme;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        delCount += i;
        // Ensure anything else gets committed.
        this.commit();
        print("*****************************************", false);
        print("** B.INV226 TOTAL DELETES OF GBL RECORDS OLDER THAN " + Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1095, false);
        print("** TOTAL RECORDS DELETED = " + delCount, false);
        print("** EDD003 Cleanup Ends : " + date(YearFormat.YYYY) + " " + getTime(), false);
        print("*****************************************", false);
        print(" ", false);

        this.webDone();
    }
}
```

edit: I know I need another loop somewhere, probably near the SQL statement itself

edit: I'd like to avoid restructuring the job or a very code heavy solution. I believe this can be accomplished with a simple loop near my SQL but can't figure out the logic

Comment: Spring batch is tagged - search on _spring batch paging item reader_, and _database paging_ in general.  Each database implements paging in different ways, although spring batch supports the common databases out of the box.

Comment: @AndrewS I figured I wouldn't have to get into an item reader, rather add a loop of some sort to say 'while x is true, execute the sql call again'

Comment: `JdbcPagingItemReader` does that loop for you.

Comment: Or simple: adjust the X in "offset X rows ", instead of leaving it at zero? Before they all come bogging you with libraries...

Comment: @JayC667 How will changing the offset allow the code to grab another 5,000 rows once it has completed the first 5,000? I'm reading into it but offset seems to exclude records

Comment: Yeah, once you put the fetch and delete into the same loop, and in that order, you will not have to change the offset. *But*, if you cannot delete certain entries (foreign key constraints etc) then you could increase the offset counter by as many as you could NOT delete, and keep iterating, until delList.size<1. Example: Try to delete 5000, but cannot delete 432 items. So next request is `offset 432 rows`. From the next you cannot delete 17. So next request would be `offset 449 rows` and so on...

Comment: Because if you keep going like you do and cannot delete >= 5000 items, your code will grab the first 5000 entries, of which eventually 5000 will not be deletable, and thus get stuck there, never ever being able to proceed beyond, to the rest of the deletable items, making any further cleanups impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up solving my own problem.

Here's the code snippet

```
 while (true) {
            MList<Fax> delList = new MList<>(Fax.class, //
                    "CREATE_DATE < ? " //
                            + "order by CREATE_DATE " //
                            + "offset 0 rows " //
                            + "fetch next 5000 rows ONLY", //
                    limitDate);
            if (delList.size() == 0) {
                break;
            }
```

This will continually execute the code until the list returns empty. Thanks for all the replies and ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Batch provides the [chunk-oriented processing model](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/step.html#chunkOrientedProcessing) which is what you are looking for. You can write a Spring Batch job with a chunk-oriented step having a chunk size of 5000.

You can find many examples of how to write such jobs in the [spring-batch-samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples) module.

Comment: I thought I could add a simple loop here that would fetch the next 5,000 rows after the first 5,000 were completed

Comment: Certainly there is a way to fix your issue by adding a loop, but since you tagged the question with `spring-batch`, I tried to give you an answer on how to do it with Spring Batch.

Comment: Thank you, your input is always helpful and appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Well,

Judging quickly from your code, the loop is where the removal of the rows happen, which means that you load in 5000 rows at a time and probably need to re-run the script until there is nothing left.

Why not do a simple SQL where you check how many rows there are left in the DB, and have a while statment that checks this?

```
while(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM *tablename* > 0 ) {
   *your code*
}
```

Even if you remove rows in the while loop, when the checking occurs again the DB will have a new value for the `COUNT()` function, meaning that it will check until there are no more rows left.

Comment: This makes sense, I'm just not sure how to implement this solution into my existing code